# jndi + spring tutorial

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, jndi

I am new to `JNDI` and `Spring MVC` is there any tutorial or blog link that can help me to understand how to configure jndi with spring to connect mysql.

I need to connect my spring application using jndi global resources but i can't understand how can i configure it with spring?

I refer [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) .

Is there any tutorial that help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know enough of Spring to setup a Spring MVC application without JNDI, then I'll point you to the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html), section C.2.3. The jee schema will help you connect your beans to JNDI resources.